# Using VBA how to highlight row in SAP GUI

Tags: vba, ms-access, sap-gui

[image: Screenshot]

So in this screenshot I would like to do a line search to find a specific text which will be `CON-` from the "Mfr part number" column, once it finds it I would like for it to highlight the line. I am having a difficult time trying to figure which way to approach this. The line of code that does highlight the line is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```vb
sapsession.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTAXI_TABSTRIP_OVERVIEW/tabpT\01/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPMV45A:4400/subSUBSCREEN_TC:SAPMV45A:4900/tblSAPMV45ATCTRL_U_ERF_AUFTRAG").getAbsoluteRow(2).Selected = True
```

Comment: You want to highlight line or part of string? The only way I know to highlight parts of text string in Access is with RichText. RichText uses HTML tags. No idea how this can be translated to SAP gui. Is image displaying a table?

Comment: I am going to safely assume it is in a table format as there are columns and rows that i can use for reference.

Comment: I guess your question is not about "Using VBA how to highlight row" but "Using VBA how to search text in cells of a Table Control", because you already know how to "highlight" (select) a given row. Right? The possible methods and properties are given [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/product/sap_gui_for_windows/760.02/en-US?q=GuiTableControl). You will be interested by the method `GetCell` and you need to handle the vertical scrolling with properties `RowCount` and `VisibleRowCount`, and paging down via `sapsession.ActiveWindow.SendVKey 82`.